# How can we configure new XML field to request after Datamapper mediator in WSO2 workflow?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gccSL.png)The user requesting with 3 fields and request format is in JSON. What I want to do is convert that request in XML using a data mapper mediator. Now after conversion, my request converts into XML. Now I want to add a new XML field to the same request in XML. Can anyone suggest to me or guide me how can we achieve it using wso2 integration studio.

WSO2 Integration studio:- Version 7.0.0
Integrator :- 6.6.0

In the request from User, I am receiving 3-4 fields in JSON format, Fields name is Account Number, NIC, RequestId.This fields I am going to convert into xml. Now i want to add static xml schema to genearted xml and this complete xml goes as request to my api

Below is process. Please suggest how i can achieve this.
1. Request from Client in json. which conatin 3-4 fields as below.

```
{
  "FIXML":{
   "@schemaLocation": "http://www.finacle.com/fixml executeFinacleScript.xsd", 
 "Body": {
         "executeFinacleScript_CustomData": {
            "ACCT_NUM": "01122507576",
            "PHONE_NUM": "59887834",
            "NIC": "G2105493001653"
         }
      }
   }
}

2. My endpoint need XML as a response and I want to store static XML schema somewhere. My static schema as below. which also has TimeZone and DateTime fields which I also want to update before requesting to the endpoint.
<FIXML>
  <Header>
    <RequestHeader>
      <MessageKey>
        <RequestUUID>FEBA_1553756445880
        </RequestUUID>
        <ServiceRequestId>executeFinacleScript
        </ServiceRequestId>
        <ServiceRequestVersion>10.2
        </ServiceRequestVersion>
        <ChannelId>COR
        </ChannelId>
      </MessageKey>
      <RequestMessageInfo>
        <BankId>04
        </BankId>
        **<TimeZone>GMT+05:00
        </TimeZone>
        <MessageDateTime>2019-03-28T11:00:45.880
        </MessageDateTime>**
      </RequestMessageInfo>
      <Security>
        <Token>
          <PasswordToken>
            <UserId>11111.0
            </UserId>
          </PasswordToken>
        </Token>
      </Security>
    </RequestHeader>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <executeFinacleScriptRequest>
      <ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
        <requestId>validateAcct.scr
        </requestId>
      </ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
      <executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
        **<ACCT_NUM>01122507576
        </ACCT_NUM>
        <PHONE_NUM>5.9887834E7
        </PHONE_NUM>
        <NIC>G2105493001653
        </NIC>**
      </executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
    </executeFinacleScriptRequest>
  </Body>
</FIXML>
```

Fields highlighted in body section of XML schema are one which I want to update from client request (JSON request coming from the client) and field highlighted in the Header section is date time and time zone **(who I can update this with latest time )**

This whole schema is my request to my endpoint. Also, how can I store static fields coming in request (Account Number, Nic ) to use it in response block?

Original XML as below

```
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml executeFinacleScript.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <RequestHeader>
      <MessageKey>
        <RequestUUID>FEBA_1553756445880</RequestUUID>
        <ServiceRequestId>executeFinacleScript</ServiceRequestId>
        <ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion>
        <ChannelId>COR</ChannelId>
      </MessageKey>
      <RequestMessageInfo>
        <BankId>04</BankId>
        <TimeZone>GMT+05:00</TimeZone>
        <EntityId></EntityId>
        <EntityType></EntityType>
        <ArmCorrelationId></ArmCorrelationId>
        <MessageDateTime>2019-03-28T11:00:45.880</MessageDateTime>
    </RequestMessageInfo>
      <Security>
        <Token>
          <PasswordToken>
          <UserId>11111</UserId>
          <Password></Password>
          </PasswordToken>
        </Token>
        <FICertToken></FICertToken>
        <RealUserLoginSessionId></RealUserLoginSessionId>
        <RealUser></RealUser>
        <RealUserPwd></RealUserPwd>
        <SSOTransferToken></SSOTransferToken>
      </Security>
    </RequestHeader>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <executeFinacleScriptRequest>
      <ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
        <requestId>validateAcct.scr</requestId>
      </ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
      <executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
        <ACCT_NUM>01122507576</ACCT_NUM>
        <PHONE_NUM>59887834</PHONE_NUM>
        <NIC>G2105493001653</NIC>
      </executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
    </executeFinacleScriptRequest>
  </Body>
</FIXML>
```

JSON conversion of above one as below

```
{
    "FIXML": {
        "Header": {
            "RequestHeader": {
                "MessageKey": {
                    "RequestUUID": "FEBA_1553756445880",
                    "ServiceRequestId": "executeFinacleScript",
                    "ServiceRequestVersion": "10.2",
                    "ChannelId": "COR"
                },
                "RequestMessageInfo": {
                    "BankId": "04",
                    "TimeZone": "GMT+05:00",
                    "EntityId": "",
                    "EntityType": "",
                    "ArmCorrelationId": "",
                    "MessageDateTime": "2019-03-28T11:00:45.880"
                },
                "Security": {
                    "Token": {
                        "PasswordToken": {
                            "UserId": "11111",
                            "Password": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "FICertToken": "",
                    "RealUserLoginSessionId": "",
                    "RealUser": "",
                    "RealUserPwd": "",
                    "SSOTransferToken": ""
                }
            }
        },
        "Body": {
            "executeFinacleScriptRequest": {
                "ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO": {
                    "requestId": "validateAcct.scr"
                },
                "executeFinacleScript_CustomData": {
                    "ACCT_NUM": "01122507576",
                    "PHONE_NUM": "59887834",
                    "NIC": "G2105493001653"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's the use of this configurable field? What it contains?

Comment: Hi, @PramodyaMendis I want to send XML to my API (EndPoint). But in the request, I received 3 parameters in JSON which I am going to map to my XML schema. After that, I want to add new XML nodes to XML generated in the data mapper response and send it to an endpoint. In between, I also want to save static fields (Request which I am receiving from the client)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your usecase, I would like to suggest a Payload Mediator approach, rather than using Datamapper. Please find the below example sequence for a PayloadMediator.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <Person xmlns="">
                <AccountNumber>$1</AccountNumber>
                <NIC>$2</NIC>
                <RequestId>$3</RequestId>
                <static>Payload</static>
            </Person>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.AccountNumber"/>
            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.NIC"/>
            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.RequestId"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

This way you can define the static payload inline within the the xml and pass the json values as arguments. This approach is simpler and more efficient than using Datamapper.

But if you still want to use datamapper, you can use an XSLT mediator to add the new XML field to the payload. You can use below XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="/Person">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <static>Payload</static>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use Datamapper itself to add a constant to the output payload. Please refer to the below example.

[image: Integration Studio Datamapper]

Comment: Hi @Arunan i am getting error while sending whole xml as inline to my end point.<problem xmlns="urn:ietf:rfc:7807"><status>400</status><title>One or more validation errors occurred.</title><traceId>0HLTRB1U375AS:00000001</traceId><MVC-Errors><MVC-Empty>Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: &lt;. Path '', line 0, position 0.</MVC-Empty></MVC-Errors></problem>* Closing connection 0

Comment: @MayurWaghulde From where are you getting this error? From your backend?

Comment: Hi @Arunan one of biggest challange i face now is ..In normal case i am not able to convert my json to xml using datamapper. I have XML schema and i convert that using online tool to json. In datamapper i upload json as input and xml as output. and just respond the result. But getting error ....DataMapper mediator : mapping failed Error while reading input stream. Script engine unable to execute the script javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "Header" from undefined in <eval> at line number 8

Comment: has solved the issue commented above...It was due to namespaces. Can you please help me with rest how can I achieve. I have shared XML above in which there are time zone, DateTime fields, AccountNumber, NIC of which some of fields i am getting from request and some i have to update like current time and time zone and keep it some where so i can use it as well in response flow. But above xml should be passed as input to my endpoint.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a Payload Factory mediator. When the client request comes, retrieve the relevant values and store them in properties. Then use a PayloadFactory mediator and create the XML payload by passing arguments. Since you have stored the values as properties you can use them when the response from the endpoint comes as well.

Comment: You mean I can create required XML in PayloadFactory mediator itself and populate values which I required and the same XML is passed to endpoint right? Is that XML will be like above one with namespaces. Can you post screencast how can I do it I mean what to select in payload property? I will try that

Comment: Hi @ArunanSugunakumar I am getting below error when i configure payload factory..  [2020-02-27 18:10:01,235] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator} - Error creating JSON Payload from source <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
{
  "FIXML":{
   "@schemaLocation": "http://www.finacle.com/fixml executeFinacleScript.xsd", 
 "Body": {
         "executeFinacleScript_CustomData": {
            "ACCT_NUM": ["1"],
            "PHONE_NUM": ["2"],
            "NIC":["G"]
         }
      }
   }

Comment: Check whether your media-type is XML or JSON. In your case it should be XML right? Look at my sample code above

Comment: Yes @Arunan Have done it with json (a sample for testing). How can i update         <TimeZone>GMT+05:00</TimeZone> and         <MessageDateTime>2019-03-28T11:00:45.880</MessageDateTime> , can you please guide me here with expression. I am searching and get expression which they hagve used in property mediatior.

Comment: can you guide me here. I did not want <jsonelement> generated .I just want value . How can we achive this <executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
                <ACCT_NUM>
                    <jsonElement>1</jsonElement>
                </ACCT_NUM>
                <PHONE_NUM>
                    <jsonElement>2</jsonElement>
                </PHONE_NUM>
                <NIC>
                    <jsonElement>G</jsonElement>
                </NIC>
            </executeFinacleScript_CustomData>

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]Thankyou Arunan for your continuous support. Have implemented it using payload mediator  successfully as suggested by you.

Payload mediator:- 
1. You can take there inline XML or JSON schema as per your requirements. In my case, I have taken inline XML which further requests to my endpoint.

How does it work?
Suppose you are requesting some JSON fields and you want some static fields to add in the same schema and further want output in XML. So now you can define XML schema (complete schema as per your requirements in the payload) and update elements value in that inline XML schema using JSON path expression.  JSON Path expression when input request is in JSON and you want to access the element value the same XPath expression for XML.

JSON Path expression:- $. (complete json request)
Xpath expression :-  /RootTag of XML (Complete XML Body)

The output of the payload factory mediator:- 
It is a SOAP XML

Why not Datamapper?
One of the most important things you need to consider while using data mapper is you need the correct Schema of both input and output. If the schema is not proper it won't work, a small change can affect. But it is also one of the most efficient ways to do. It directly maps and convert your request to XML, JSON, CSV and also given some calculative approach to do manipulation on data of request.